# Where does Goldmine store users and user groups?

Tags: sql-server, migration, crm, suitecrm, goldmine

I'm about to migrate from Goldmine database to Suitecrm database. In Goldmine they have user groups and members, Im unable to locate that table where the groups/membership for each users has been stored in the Goldmine database. Can you please help me at the earlist!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

GoldMine stores the group membership in the U_security field in the users table. Unfortunately it is encrypted by the application and you will require the API to get access to it.